# Node.js on Openshift: Keep getting timeouts even with low load and HAProxy

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have a node app on openshift and am now constantly suffering from timeouts even though the logs show a lot of idling around. I even have started a second gear and am using HAproxy. Any ideas what could be done? Or how to even debug the problem?

It just suddenly started to happen, without any changes from me to the system. No additional traffic either and the database functions fine and is definitely not the bottleneck.

Comment: Does the application restarts itself again and again?

Comment: @Meir: No, the application keeps running. It just looks like it does not serve any data. But it also does not scale up any additional  gears

Comment: strange. They introduced recently a `/health` endpoint you have to implement, it's in the new app template:
app.get('/health', function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
}); I wonder if it has to do with it

Comment: @Meir I don't think that should be the problem. I can see the proxy doing the health check every second or so and the health check returns 200 as it should.

Comment: And just for completeness sake, when the HAProxy interface is not timing out, it does not show more than 1 or 2 connections per gear. And the app returns any page requests within 100ms. So it should not be the number of connections or anything like that.